# Check array for equals elements

Tags: extjs

Hello i am have array (price), and when i am click button this array check for same elements and if all elements equals than do function if elements different then nothing doing

```
priceCheck: function(button) {
      var win = button.up('window'),
      grid = win.down('grid'),
        price=[];
           Ext.each(grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection(), function(value, rowIndex) {
                   price.push(value.get('price'));
                    console.log(price) });}
```

And example of condition:

```
if (?elements equals?) {some function}  else nothing;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered in the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Array-method-equals), use the `equals` method which does a shallow compare.

```
if (Ext.Array.equals([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])) {
    // do something
}
```